# Are you able to access a variable that has function scope when unit testing with Jest/Vitest?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, vitest

Let's say we have a function, `myFunction` that we want to test.

myFunction.js

```
const myFunction = anotherFunction => {
  const x = Math.random()
  let foo

  if(x > 0.5) foo = true
  if(x < 0.5) foo = false

  anotherFunction(foo)
  return
}

export default myFunction
```

Is it possible to have access to the variable `foo` after executing the function in jest/vitest?

myFunction.test.js

```
import myFunction from "./myFunction.js"
import { test } from "vitest"
    
test("myFunction", () => {
  myFunction()
  //can the `foo` variable from within myFunction be accessed in this test?
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One note: unit testing with MathRandom will leave undeterministic results!

The way you want is not possible. But it can be achieved with another approach. In order to control the cases you need to control what `Math.random()` will return on each execution;

I will propose some modifications to your function so that math is optionally  injected from the function consumer

```js
const myFunction = (anotherFunction, math = Math) => {
  const x = math.random()
  let foo

  if(x > 0.5) foo = true
  if(x < 0.5) foo = false

  anotherFunction(foo)
  return
}

export default myFunction
```

And now in the test we provide a jest mock with attached spy and dummy predictable Math random implementation. We can now inspect with what params the other function has been called.

```js
const getMathRandomMock = (result) => {
  return {
    random: () => result
  }
}

test("myFunction", () => {
  const anotherFuncMock = jest.fn();
  myFunction(anotherFuncMock, getMathRandomMock(0.4))
  expect(anotherFuncMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(false)
})
```

Comment: This solution would work in this case. I used this case for demostration purposes. In my specific case. I have a deterministic variable scoped to the function. It's value is based on conditions of the arguments passed to the function and I want to assert if the variable holds the value I expect based on those conditions.

Comment: @Jonathan extract the calculation of the variable in its own function and test it separately